# Making byobu's (using tmux) status bar multi-line results in "session" and the date/time disappearing

Tags: tmux, byobu

I added

```
set-option -g status 2
set -g status-format[0] '#[align=left]#(byobu-status tmux_left)'
set -g status-format[1] '#[align=right]#(byobu-status tmux_right)'
```

to my profile.tmux file and now the "session" stuff (tabs) in the top line has disappeared and also the date and time has disappeared from the bottom line. The logo and version are still in the top line, and every other status notification thing I have set is still in the bottom line. I haven't changed anything in the "status" file with the lines of "tmux_left" and "tmux_right". Can someone please help me get this straightened out?

EDIT: I was able to get this somewhat working. I am now unable to select a window via a mouse click. This is what I have in my profile.tmux file:

```
source $BYOBU_PREFIX/share/byobu/profiles/tmux
set -g window-status-format "#[bg=$BYOBU_DARK,fg=$BYOBU_LIGHT,none]"
set -g window-status-current-format "#[bg=$BYOBU_LIGHT,fg=$BYOBU_DARK,bold]"
set-window-option -g window-status-activity-style bg=$BYOBU_DARK,fg=$BYOBU_LIGHT,bold
set-option -g status 2
set -g status-format[0] ' #[align=left]#{W:#{?#{#{==:#{window_index},0}},,| }#{?#{window_active},#{E:window-status-current-format},#{E:window-status-format}} #I:#W #{E:window-status-format} }'
set -g status-format[1] '#[align=left]#(byobu-status tmux_left)'
set -ag status-format[1] '#[align=right]#(byobu-status tmux_right)'$BYOBU_DATE$BYOBU_TIME
```

Can someone PLEASE help me???